# Google Maps API XML File Not Loading

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to load markers from an XML file into a Google Maps page, similar to the example detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps).

I copied the code found on the page, inserting my API key instead, and it worked fine.

```
 // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
```

However, I am unable to get the markers to appear when using a local XML file. I even downloaded the mapmarkers2 xml file from the example above, and saved it locally. This version did not run either, but when I switch to using the same file hosted online, it works fine. I tried hosting the file on an AWS server, which didn't work either.

Comment: `// Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file ` .... did you do this? Reading  instructions is your best bet.

Comment: Yes, that is the only line I changed from the source code. I switched it to a local version of the same XML file, which didn't work. When I reset it back to the original URL, it does. Not sure where I'm going wrong. 

Edit: I should mention that both the HTML and the local XML file are saved in the same directory as well.

Comment: If you could show how you write that changed line, would be helpful? Very much. If you dont want to then know that `./` is current path.

Comment: Ok. Are you testing all this out from a local server? That part *matters*.  You need file system access that you only get from a server. Try xampp if on windows

Comment: Deleted my other comment because of formatting issues.

Sure - I do it one of two ways. Censored identifying info with &&

1) S3 Server: downloadUrl('https://&&/s3.amazonaws.com/XML/mapmarkers2.xml'

2) Local File: downloadUrl('C:\Users\&&\Documents\Misc\mapmarkers2.xml'

The rest of the code remains the same.

Comment: Yes, this is all being done from a local server! Do I need to configure it to access local XML files?

Comment: Your project would go in htdocs of c:\xampp\

Comment: No, xml is plain text

Comment: What is your path to the xml in your app? The whole line?

Comment: You should NOT use a filesystem path such as `C:\Users\&&\Documents\Misc\mapmarkers2.xml` as Javascript cannot read from the filesystem - it should be a file within the structure defined by the webserver config

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a reason hosting the file on an S3 server doesn't seem to work as well?

Comment: Whatever location the XML file is stored should be accessible to Javascript. If you have hosted the XML file on S3 and are trying to access from your testing server/client then there may well be issues with Cross Origin resources - think: `preflighted requests` / CORS

Comment: The example code and xml just works for me on my server (in Chrome and Firefox): http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_MySQL_PHP_map.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `downloadURL` from w3schools you might wish to consider the `fetch` api, especially for instances where you need to negotiate CORS requests. In the code below the XML file was simply stored in the same directory as the HTML page and the data retrieved using `fetch`. Bizarrely however this new API, designed to replace the abused XMLHttpRequest, has no native methods for returning XML data directly so an addition step is required where the response data is parsed through the `DOMParser` before further processing.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: read XML file...</title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                var map;
                
                const addmarker=( latlng, title, config={} )=>{
                    let options={
                        position:latlng,
                        title:title,
                        map:map
                    };
                    options=Object.assign( options, config );
                    
                    let marker=new google.maps.Marker( options );
                    
                    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(e){
                        console.info( this )
                    }.bind( marker ));
                    
                    return marker;
                };
                
                const attrib=(n,a)=>{
                    return n.getAttribute(a);
                };
                
                
                fetch( 'mapmarkers2.xml' )
                    .then( r=>{ return r.text() })
                    .then( str => ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString( str, 'text/xml' ) )
                    .then( xml=>{
                        let col=xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
                        
                        let options = {
                            zoom: 12,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng( -33.853985, 151.099404 ),
                        };
                        map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
                        
                        Array.from( col ).forEach( mkr=>{
                            let id=attrib(mkr,'id');
                            let name=attrib(mkr,'name');
                            let address=attrib(mkr,'address');
                            let type=attrib(mkr,'type');
                            let lat=attrib(mkr,'lat');
                            let lng=attrib(mkr,'lng');

                            let config={
                                'id':id,
                                'name':name,
                                'address':address,
                                'type':type
                            };
                            
                            addmarker( new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng), name, config  );
                        });
                    })
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXYYYZZZ&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```